# Async same time as Sync c# simple console app

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5

Im trying to write my first async app and ensure its working concurrently. The problem is i wrote the same app synchronously and i dont see a time difference.

```
class Program
{
 private static List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
 Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();      
    var waitOne = Load(1000);
 Task.WhenAll(waitOne);
  Console.WriteLine("Done Time:" + (s.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000).ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
    static async Task Load(int i)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < i; y++)
    {
        List1.Add(callWcf(y).Result);
    }

    await Task.Yield();
}
static async Task<string> callWcf(int i)
{
    string here;

    using (ServiceReference1.Client client = new AsyncTests.ServiceReference1.Client())
    {
        here = client.GetThisInt(i);
    }
    await Task.Yield();
    return here;

}
}
```

The WCF service is a simple service i built from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx;

Returns "You entered {0}"

I did the same code synchronously and they both take 8 seconds for 1000 iterations, which is fast but i think my async is wrong as it should be faster that the synchronous. Ive followed tutorials, listened to a few podcasts and i know im missing something but i dont know what.

Comment: You're _completely_ misunderstanding async.

Comment: async doesn't make things faster; it allows better scalability & parallelism.  And you aren't actually doing any async work.

Comment: Slaks - Please enlighten me, you seem to say i dont understand and im doing it wrong, yet you give no explanation, please elaborate. How would i best execute the above code with async operations? Essentially i would like to open (x) threads and have them run concurrently. I also stated " i know im missing something but i dont know what."

Comment: The actual operation you're doing (`client.GetThisInt`) is still synchronous.  You need an async version of that which uses async network IO.

Comment: The whole point of async is to _not_ have (x) threads waiting for responses, but to kick off asynchronous requests that notify you when they finish, without using any threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) you may find helpful.

Asynchronous code does not always run faster. In fact, a straight line-by-line translation to asynchronous code usually runs *slower*. The key benefit of asynchronous code is concurrency: it frees up the calling thread to do other work while the asynchronous operation is in progress.

To review your code:

```
Task.WhenAll(waitOne);
```

This doesn't actually do anything. `WhenAll` will return a `Task` that completes when `waitOne` completes, but then the task returned from `WhenAll` is ignored.

```
List1.Add(callWcf(y).Result);
```

Here your code stars an asynchronous operation (`callWcf`) and then turns around and immediately and synchronously blocks waiting for it to complete (`Result`).

```
await Task.Yield();
```

This code is pointless. Apparently it's only there to silence the compiler warnings about `async` methods not containing an `await`.

```
here = client.GetThisInt(i);
```

And here the code is synchronously blocking again.

As I describe in my [async best practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), one of the principles of `async` is to use "async all the way". It's easiest to do this from the lowest level (look for anything I/O-based) and work your way up. In this case, the best place to start is the WCF call:

```
static async Task<string> CallWcfAsync(int i)
{
  using (ServiceReference1.Client client = new AsyncTests.ServiceReference1.Client())
  {
    return await client.GetThisIntAsync(i);
  }
}
```

I also changed the method name to match the [TAP conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Next, you move to the caller(s) of that method:

```
static async Task Load(int i)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < i; y++)
  {
    List1.Add(await CallWcfAsync(y));
  }
}
```

or if you want to execute multiple calls simultaneously:

```
static async Task LoadAsync(int i)
{
  var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, i).Select(y => CallWcfAsync(y));
  List1.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));
}
```

Finally, your `Main` method does have to block on a task; this is one of the very rare situations where calling `Result` or `Wait` is permissible:

```
LoadAsync(1000).Wait();
```

Comment: If you're going to fix the whole thing up to proper design, it would also be best for the list to be returned as the result of the task, rather than causing the side effect of mutating a static variable.  The latter opens up many more holes for possible unsafe access to state shared between threads.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, the line by line was very useful. I do have one question, The WCF is per call, so why does the server-side code need to be told to be Async? My best intentions for this code was to spawn as many threads for calling the service, i thought Async worked like this: Spawn Async thread, dont wait, let me know when it finishes. So again, why would the WCF service wait for a blocking response?

Comment: This code is all client-side. You're not telling the server code to be async; you're telling the client proxy to be async. And async does not spawn any threads.

Comment: If the server side is multithreaded without Async would it still block or would they all run concurrently?

Comment: They would run concurrently if the server is multithreaded or async and the service was configured to allow concurrent access.